# Update excel table using power automate

Tags: excel, power-automate, excel-tables, power-automate-desktop

I am using power automate to add a row to a table on excel File located in share point using data from a query in azure dev ops. It works fine, it adds the data. However, I need to find a way to refresh the table and delete the previews rows and columns and update it with the new info coming from the query. How do I delete the content and update the table??

I have tried update row and it only does it for the first row.

Comment: Show us your flow with the update step open and visible. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your Power Automate flow should contain these steps in order:

1. Get all rows from the Excel table
2. Filter the results to the rows you need to delete
3. Create the new row as you already implemented
4. Iterate the filtered array and use the [Delete a row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#delete-a-row) action

This way the previous data is only deleted if the new data is successfully recorded.

Comment: so, the commands I will need to use in power automate will be 1-get a row. 2- list a row. 3- add a row in to a table, 4 delete a row?

Comment: Not exactly. First you get all rows https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#list-rows-present-in-a-table, and the second step is filtering the rows https://debajmecrm.com/how-to-filter-array-in-power-automate-flow/